# How to initialize the variable and increment it in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to initialize the variable and increment it in the  for loop but I'm getting the following error:

**Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'endspaceless'**

This is my code:

```
<tr{{ row.attr_string|safe }}>
    {% spaceless %}

        {% set counter = 0 %}

        {% for cell in row %}

           {% set counter= counter+1 %}

           {% if counter < 4 %}                 
                {%  include "horizon/common/_data_grid_cell.html" %}           
           {% else %}
                {%  include "horizon/common/_data_table_cell.html" %}
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endspaceless %}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to. Django already comes with a [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for), as well as a `forloop.counter0`. You can use it directly:

```
<tr{{ row.attr_string|safe }}>
    {% spaceless %}

        {% for cell in row %}

           {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}                 
                {%  include "horizon/common/_data_grid_cell.html" %}           
           {% else %}
                {%  include "horizon/common/_data_table_cell.html" %}
           {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endspaceless %}
</tr>
```